# Pause sending messages in loop, wait for user tap InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

User insert some values. Just for not spamming him with many messages, I want to pause sending them in loop and wait user tap inline button. So how can I pause them and wait for user tap "Next result" button? Code beneath just simplified, but works for better understanding scenario.

```
import os

from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State


bot = Bot(token=os.environ["TOKEN"])
dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


class Searches(StatesGroup):
    by_id = State()


@dispatcher.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
async def cancel_state(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if await state.get_state():
        await state.finish()
        await message.reply("Search was canceled")


@dispatcher.message_handler(commands="search")
async def answer_search_message(message: types.Message):
    find_by_id_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("по ID", callback_data="by_id")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(find_by_id_button)
    await message.answer("Choose search type", parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(text="by_id")
async def callback_id(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer("Insert IDs, split them with ','")
    await Searches.by_id.set()


@dispatcher.message_handler(state=Searches.by_id)
async def find_by_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    ids_from_message = [item for item in range(5)]  # get IDs from user message
    for index, item in enumerate(ids_from_message):
        photo, caption, url = ("https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", "some text", "https://www.example.org/")  # get some data by id
        button_to_site = types.InlineKeyboardButton("More on site", url)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(button_to_site)
        if len(ids_from_message) > index + 1:  # if this is not last result - show button "Next result"
            keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Next result", callback_data="show_next"))
            await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
            # loop should pause here, awaiting for user tap inline button "Next result"
        else:
            await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
            await state.finish()


executor.start_polling(dispatcher)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, internet, you always helps me, so here what I found as solution for this problem. You can just save some data for user and send it to him, then it trigger button. Full code below.

```
import os

from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State


def get_record_by_id(doc_id):
    # blah-blah some data generating
    return "https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", "текст документа", "https://www.example.org/"


bot = Bot(token=os.environ["TOKEN"])
storage = MemoryStorage()
dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Searches(StatesGroup):
    by_id = State()


@dispatcher.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
async def cancel_state(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if await state.get_state():
        await state.finish()
        await message.reply("Search was canceled")


@dispatcher.message_handler(commands="search")
async def answer_search_message(message: types.Message):
    find_by_id_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("by ID", callback_data="by_id")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(find_by_id_button)
    await message.answer("Choose search type", parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(text="by_id")
async def callback_id(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer("Insert IDs, split them with ','")
    await Searches.by_id.set()
    await callback.answer()


@dispatcher.message_handler(state=Searches.by_id)
async def find_by_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    ids_from_message = [item for item in range(5)]
    photo, caption, url = get_record_by_id(ids_from_message[0])
    button_to_site = types.InlineKeyboardButton("More on site", url)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(button_to_site)
    if len(ids_from_message) > 1:
        del ids_from_message[0]
        await storage.set_data(user=user_id, data={"ids_to_send": ids_from_message})
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Next result", callback_data="show_next"))
        await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.finish()


@dispatcher.callback_query_handler(state=Searches.by_id, text="show_next")
async def callback_id(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = callback.from_user.id
    chat_id = callback.message.chat.id
    data = await storage.get_data(user=user_id)
    photo, caption, url = get_record_by_id(data["ids_to_send"][0])
    button_to_site = types.InlineKeyboardButton("More on site", url)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(button_to_site)
    if len(data["ids_to_send"]) > 1:
        del data["ids_to_send"][0]
        await storage.set_data(user=user_id, data={"ids_to_send": data["ids_to_send"]})
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Next result", callback_data="show_next"))
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=photo, caption=caption, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.finish()
    await callback.answer()


executor.start_polling(dispatcher)
```